# Cannot borrow variable as mutable more than once at a time after calling a &'a mut self method

Tags: rust

I have a problem with lifetimes/borrowing with my `Graph` object.

```
fn main() {
    let mut g = Graph {
        nodePointer: &mut 0,
        edgePointer: &mut 0,
        nodes: &mut Vec::new(),
        edges: &mut Vec::new(),
    };
    let node1 = g.add_node((1, 1));
    let node2 = g.get_node(0);
}

pub struct Graph<'a> {
    pub nodePointer: &'a mut usize,
    pub edgePointer: &'a mut usize,
    pub nodes: &'a mut Vec<Node>,
    pub edges: &'a mut Vec<Edge>,
}

impl<'a> Graph<'a> {
    pub fn add_node(&'a mut self, data: (u64, u64)) -> usize {
        let id: usize = *self.nodePointer;
        self.nodes.push(Node {
            id: id,
            datum: data,
        });
        *self.nodePointer += 1;
        return id;
    }

    pub fn get_node(&'a mut self, id: usize) -> &'a Node {
        return &self.nodes[id];
    }

    pub fn add_edge(&'a mut self, source: u64, target: u64, weight: u16) -> usize {
        let id: usize = *self.nodePointer;
        self.edges.push(Edge {
            id: id,
            source,
            target,
            weight,
        });
        *self.edgePointer = *self.edgePointer + 1;
        return id;
    }
}

pub struct Node {
    pub id: usize,
    pub datum: (u64, u64),
}

pub struct Edge {
    pub id: usize,
    pub source: u64,
    pub target: u64,
    pub weight: u16,
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `g` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:9:17
   |
8  |     let node1 = g.add_node((1, 1));
   |                 - first mutable borrow occurs here
9  |     let node2 = g.get_node(0);
   |                 ^ second mutable borrow occurs here
10 | }
   | - first borrow ends here
```

Comment: This *is* a weird one. Logically it seems like `add_node` should return a *copy* of `id` and shouldn't leave you with an outstanding borrow...

Comment: Wait, no, I have your problem. Give me a second to write up your solution.

Comment: Rather than just the one line you think is important and no context at all, it's better if you include the full error message in your question. Your example could also be shorter: you get the same error if you remove everything about edges.

Comment: Why do you even have all these references? Why not make them value members?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem arises from a misuse of lifetimes, specifically in your signature of `add_node`:

```
pub fn add_node(&'a mut self, data: (u64, u64)) -> usize
```

In this signature, you are stating that `add_node` takes an `&'a mut self` on a `Graph<'a>`; in other words, you are telling Rust that this method needs to take a mutable borrow on the graph that can't be dropped before the end of the Graph's lifetime, `'a`. But since it's *the graph itself* holding a reference to the graph, the only time that reference will be dropped is when the graph itself is dropped.

Since `add_node` doesn't require you to return a reference to any object within the struct, holding onto that borrow is irrelevant. If you alter your `add_node` method to remove the explicit lifetime:

```
pub fn add_node(&mut self, data: (u64, u64)) -> usize
```

then your example no longer raises an error, because `add_node` is now only borrowing `self` until it's finished with the function. (Under the hood, this effectively creates a second lifetime `'b` and makes the signature into `&'b mut self`)

See [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e646c03a0898566f66563dc37b2422a8&version=stable) for proof.

Comment: As an aside, I don't *believe* that the `&'a mut self`s in the other methods are necessary either. The `'a` needs to reflect the lifetime of the return value, *not* the borrow on the graph itself. But I could very well be wrong.

Comment: This response is awesome! Working solution & great explanation.

Comment: @NathanHorrigan While the solution works, I'd warn you to take my explanation of the **why** with a grain of salt - it's admittedly a bit of a guess at Rust's functionality, and not really my field of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this :

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    x: &'a i32,
}
```

As the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/lifetimes.html#in-structs) states:

> So why do we need a lifetime here? We need to ensure that any reference to a Foo cannot outlive the reference to an i32 it contains.

If you write something like:

```
impl<'a> Graph<'a> {
    pub fn add_node(&'a mut self, data: (u64, u64)) -> usize {
        ...
```

the lifetime declaration `&'a mut self` is not for the purpose of relating the lifetime of `Graph` instance with the contained references, 
but for declaring that for mutable `self` references hold the same lifetime `'a` declared for `Graph` field references:

```
fn main() {    
    let mut g = Graph {                          // <------------
        nodePointer: &mut 0,                     //             |            
        edgePointer: &mut 0,                     // lifetime    |
        nodes: &mut Vec::new(),                  // of Graph    | 'a
        edges: &mut Vec::new(),                  // references  |
    };                                           //             |
    let node1 = Graph::add_node(&mut g, (1, 1)); //             |   
    let node2 = Graph::get_node(&mut g, 0);      //             |
}                                                //<-------------
```

Where `g.get_node(0)` has been rewritten as `Graph::get_node(&mut g, 0)` just for explicitly exposing the `&mut` reference

Looking at the lifetime of `'a` it is clear that the reference `&mut g` is borrowed mutably more than once, and this causes the error.